# C# Regex not matching string spanning multiple line

Tags: regex, .net-core

In c# I have a regex and I can't get my head around why it is not matching.

The pattern `(abc\r\n)*` should match the `abc\r\nabc\r\n` in the string `123\r\nabc\r\nabc\r\n345`

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(abc\r\n)*", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var mat = regex.Match("123\r\nabc\r\nabc\r\n345");
```

The funny thing is that mat.Success returns true.
[image]

The same pattern matches [online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28abc%5Cr%5Cn%29*&i=123%0D%0Aabc%0D%0Aabc%0D%0A345%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Match` method works as expected.
Actually the pattern `(abc\r\n)*` will find **12 matches**. The `Match` method returns to you the **first** match only which is an empty string.
So that if you are looking to match `abc\r\nabc\r\n` exactly you should use this pattern:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(abc\r\nabc\r\n)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

if you like to match all `abc\r\n` you should use:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(abc\r\n)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var mat = regex.Matches("123\r\nabc\r\nabc\r\n345");
```

And so on, bottom line is that the problem is in the pattern itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the first 12 matches are empty?

Comment: Also, I thought that regex is greedy, and should go on to match the longest possible sequence of chars. Why is that not happening.

Comment: The "*" notation matches zero or more occurrences of the regular expression so that you get the empty strings as matches.  http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/Internet/NEWS/regexp.html